# "warning treating unicode character as whitespace -wunicode-whitespace"

Tags: c

Why am I getting the below warning and how to correct it?

> warning treating unicode character as whitespace -wunicode-whitespace

The C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int a, i, j, len, k;
    char arr[100];

    printf("Enter String:*\n");
    scanf("%s",arr);
    len = strlen(arr);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        a = 1;
        for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                k = 0;
                while (k < i)
                {
                    if (arr[k] == arr[i])
                    {
                        goto India;
                    }
                    k++;
                }
                a = a + 1;
            }
        }
        printf("The Character %c has repeated %d times\n", arr[i], a);
    India:
    }
}
```

Comment: Save the source file with ascii encoding?

Comment: This code will not compile because a label like `India:` cannot immediately precede a closing brace, like `}`. It must have a statement after it. The compiler does not complain about any issue with whitespace. I hypothesize a warning message about a whitespace character may have been caused by copying text from some external source, such as a web page, that contained an unusual character. Further, it may have been lost when you attempted to paste into Stack Overflow. Examine your source file to ensure it does not contain any unusual characters.

Comment: Note that C23 will allow labels before both declarations and close braces.  If compiling using `gcc -std=c2x`, it should be OK — but not with earlier versions of the C standard.

Comment: OT: you should format your code properly. As it stands in the question it's a total mess.

Comment: The message suggests you've got something like a non-breaking space in the source code.  When I copy'n'paste the text from the question, I don't see any non-ASCII characters, but you probably would find them.  It might be a BOM encoded in UTF-8 — which shouldn't be in the source.  You chopped off the line number information, so we can't see which line reputedly has the trouble.  If it's line 1, an encoded [BOM](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) is plausible.  Elsewhere, it is likely to be some variant of non-breaking space (there are many — ZWNJ, etc).

Comment: A BOM (byte-order mark, U+FEFF) is a ZWNBSP — zero-width non-breaking space — in the middle of a text file.  See the [BOM FAQ](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) also linked to in my prior comment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I just checked by adding a unicode character in a SO question. SO converts them to ASCII equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your code as is and it compiled fine.  However, usually when there is a "goto" used within a program, that is a flag that some alternative method should be evaluated to avoid such usage.  In this case, I did a bit of code refactoring replacing the usage of a "goto" with a "break" statement which is more usual and customary.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int a,i,j,len,k;
    char arr[100];

    printf("Enter String:*\n");
    scanf("%s",arr);
    len=strlen(arr);

    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        a=1;
        for(j=i+1; j<len; j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
                k=0;
                while(k<i)
                {
                    if(arr[k]==arr[i])
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    k++;
                }
                a=a+1;
            }
        }
        printf("The Character %c has repeated %d times\n", arr[i],a);
    }
}
```

When running the code both before and after the refactoring, I got the following test output at the terminal.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/India/bin/Release$ ./India 
Enter String:*
hello
The Character h has repeated 1 times
The Character e has repeated 1 times
The Character l has repeated 2 times
The Character l has repeated 1 times
The Character o has repeated 1 times
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/India/bin/Release$ ./India 
Enter String:*
hello
The Character h has repeated 1 times
The Character e has repeated 1 times
The Character l has repeated 2 times
The Character l has repeated 1 times
The Character o has repeated 1 times
```

In reviewing the output, again my guess is that the second result of evaluating the letter "l" in this case is not to be printed out.  With that in mind, following is some further refactoring of the code to note additional usual and customary usage of loops, tests, and breaks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main()
{
    int a = 0, len;
    char arr[SIZE + 1];

    printf("Enter String: ");
    fgets(arr, SIZE, stdin);        /* This would allow for the entry of multiple words */

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)  /* Loop through to remove newline character         */
    {
        if (arr[i] == '\n')
        {
            arr[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    len = strlen(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        a++;

        if (((i < (len - 1)) && arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) || i == (len - 1))
        {
            if (arr[i] != ' ')      /* Ignore blanks */
                printf("The Character %c has repeated %d time(s)\n", arr[i],a);
            a = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Some items to note.

- A size definition is introduced to cut down on hard-coded values that might be used throughout the program.
- The "fgets" function is utilized in lieu of the "scanf" function which would allow more flexibility if a sentence were to be entered instead of a single word/string.  If only a single word/string will always be entered, then one could stay with "scanf".
- With the change to "fgets", an additional "for" loop is added as a scrubber to remove the newline character from the entered sentence and provide the proper string length.
- Using a slightly more complex test of where the character testing is occurring, the character count can be simplified and the amount of code reduced, cutting down on possible redundancies and places where logic errors might occur.

With that, following were some more tests of various string and sentence entries.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/India/bin/Release$ ./India 
Enter String: Hello
The Character H has repeated 1 time(s)
The Character e has repeated 1 time(s)
The Character l has repeated 2 time(s)
The Character o has repeated 1 time(s)
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/India/bin/Release$ ./India 
Enter String: Hello there buzzzzzz
The Character H has repeated 1 time(s)
The Character e has repeated 1 time(s)
The Character l has repeated 2 time(s)
The Character o has repeated 1 time(s)
The Character t has repeated 1 time(s)
The Character h has repeated 1 time(s)
The Character e has repeated 1 time(s)
The Character r has repeated 1 time(s)
The Character e has repeated 1 time(s)
The Character b has repeated 1 time(s)
The Character u has repeated 1 time(s)
The Character z has repeated 6 time(s)
```

The result is most likely the desired count statistics that are to be outputted.

Give this a review.  Also, you might want to delve into some more "C" tutorial literature, especially as it pertains to loops, using the "break" statement, and so forth.

Comment: I checked by adding a unicode character in a SO question. SO converts them to ASCII equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The warning you received (**warning treating unicode character as whitespace**) is specific to clang and triggered by the presence of Unicode whitespace codepoints in the source code.

The code in [Lexer.cpp](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/lib/Lex/Lexer.cpp) checks for Unicode codepoints in the set defined by `llvm::sys::UnicodeCharRange`, ie: U+0085, U+00A0, U+1680, U+180E, U+2000 to U+200A, U+2028, U+2029, U+202F, U+205F and U+3000, as defined in Unicode v6.2, chapter 6.2, table 6-2. If such a codepoint is seen when parsing code, the warning is issued unless it was explicitly disabled with the command line option `-Wno-unicode-whitespace`.  You should inspect the source code at the lines reported by the compiler and remove any non ASCII whitespace.  These characters are not necessarily visible in the editor so may need to overwrite the whitespace with ASCII spaces entered with the space bar.  The most likely offender is the non breaking space U+00A0 which you may search for in the editor.  There is no Unicode whitespace character in the source code you posted in the question, but Stack Overflow might have converted them automatically.

Regarding the code, the main problem is the label `India:` that is not followed by a statement.  While many compilers have been supporting this as an extension for a long time, it will only become part of the C Standard as of the upcoming C23 version.  For portability, you should write `India:;`.

More generally, it is recommended to avoid using the `goto` statement.  You can change the code logic to only count potential repetitions if the character has not already been seen already.

Also note that `scanf("%s", ...)` cannot prevent buffer overflows on sufficiently long input words.  You must specify the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array as `"%99s"`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, len, count;
    char arr[100];

    printf("Enter String: ");
    if (scanf("%99s", arr) != 1)
        return 1;

    len = strlen(arr);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == arr[i])
                break;
        }
        if (j == i) {
            /* character has not been seen yet */
            count = 1;
            for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                    count++;
            }
            printf("The Character %c has repeated %d times\n", arr[i], count);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I checked by adding a unicode character in a SO question. SO converts them to ASCII equivalent.